# Getting information from array inside array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

So i have array which is something like this

```
Array (323)
0 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2000"
  aukstis => "1909"
1 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2100"
  aukstis => "1909"
2 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2200"
  aukstis => "1909"
3 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2300"
  aukstis => "1909"
4 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2400"
  aukstis => "1909"
5 => Array (2)
  plotis => "2500"
  aukstis => "1909"
and so on
```

I need to make 2 arrays 1 should have
all **plotis** value and other **aukstis** value .
But the problem is its first time i see array in array ( new to php )

Comment: Arrays of arrays are not any different than "normal" arrays. E.g. you can access the `plotis` entry of the first array with `$arr[0]['plotis']`.

Comment: Can anyone tell the method which uses least of resources because that array is quite large :/ and it incrases loading time  by quite a bit.

Comment: @user3313750: Then a simple `foreach` might prove to be faster than `array_*` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map` for this..

```
$plotis_arr  = array_map(function ($v){ return $v['plotis'];},$yourarray);
$aukstis_arr = array_map(function ($v){ return $v['aukstis'];},$yourarray);
```

Comment: Thanks you are fast tho :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a multi-dimensional array. To access the values inside the array, you need to loop through them. For this purpose, we can use the very handy `foreach` construct.

The basic syntax is as follows:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value { 
    # code ...
}
```

In this case, the code would be:

```
$plotis = $aukstis = array(); // Initialize both of them as empty arrays

foreach ($array as $sub) {
    $plotis[]  = $sub['plotis'];   // Push the values to
    $aukstis[] = $sub['aukstis'];  // respective arrays
}
```

Of course, this can be shortened down to fewer lines of code with `array_map()` and the like, but since you said you're a beginner, I thought it'd be a good idea to use a plain simple `foreach` so you could understand it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$plotis = Array();
$aukstis = Array();

for($i=0; $i<count($mainArray); $i++)
{
    $plotis[] = $mainArray[$i]['plotis'];
    $aukstis[] = $mainArray[$i]['aukstis'];
}

print_r($plotis); //to display plotis array
print_r($aukstis); //to display aukstis array
```